# PHPStorm 2017: PHPUnit coverage plugin

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, phpstorm-2017.2

I install PHPunit code coverage in PHPStorm. When I run the PHPUnit, it displays an error message:

> PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Error:         No code coverage driver is available

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install/activate XDebug or Zend-Debugger on your Web-Server. XDebug can simply be activated in the php.ini.